# Handle Case when only one out of the two ajax request got successfully executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making two ajax requests. I am able to handle the case when both the ajax request got successfully executed using jquery deferred objects. Now I want to handle the case when one gets success and the other gets failed.

`usedCarPurchaseInqPromise` and `hitRecoApi` are the two jquery deferred objects.

**CODE** :

```
var usedCarPurchaseInqPromise = D_buyerProcess.buyerProcessApis.processUsedCarPurchaseInquiries(boxObj, leadData);
usedCarPurchaseInqPromise.always(function () {
    if (isFromCaptcha == "1")
        isFromCaptcha = "0";
    if (isGSDClick == "1")
        isGSDClick = "0";
    hideBuyerForm(boxObj);
    $('#newLoading').hide();
    boxObj.find('#pg-process_img,#pg-loadingImg').hide();
    boxObj.find("#loadDetails").hide();
}).fail(function () {
    D_buyerProcess.sellerDetails.processLeadFailureResponse(boxObj, jqXHR);
});
var hitRecoApi = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: stockRecommendationsUrl_g,
    headers: { "sourceid": "1" },
    dataType: 'json'
});

$.when(usedCarPurchaseInqPromise, hitRecoApi).done(function (response, jsonData) {
    Common.utils.lockPopup();
    if (D_buyerProcess.utils.isNumberChanged(buyersMobile)) {//if user has changed number as compared to previously stored number in cookie, remove the finance offer of previous number
        if (typeof (customerFinanceUI) !== 'undefined' && typeof (customerFinance) !== 'undefined') {
            customerFinanceUI.hideFinanceOffer();
            customerFinance.removeFinanceOffer(); // removes finance cookie and storage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in that case handle the "fail" callback from $.when

Comment: I kind of got you. Can you please write a small snippet when usedCarPurchaseInqPromise gets successful and hitRecoApi gets failed.

Comment: t doesn't matter which one fails, you can handle .fail(function () { on the $.when() call. Or combine success/failure callbacks in a single "then" as per the example at the end of https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: The example at the end of the link you sent, works when either of that gets failed. I want specifically first to pass and second one to fail.

Comment: The documentation says "The arguments passed to the failCallbacks match the signature of the failCallback for the Deferred that was rejected." If you need to perform additional processing for this case, such as canceling any unfinished Ajax requests, you can keep references to the underlying jqXHR objects in a closure and inspect/cancel them in the failCallback." So you have to do a bit of work but you should be able to figure out which one failed.

Comment: Bear in mind though that $.when will launch the failCallback as soon as one request fails. It doesn't wait for the others to complete. So you may know that one of them has failed, but you may or may not at that moment know whether the other one has failed or succeeded

Comment: If you look around the internet there are a couple of (amateur) implementations of a "whenAll" function, which waits for all the callbacks to complete before resolving or rejecting itself. You still have to do a little bit of work to find out which one(s) failed though, I would think.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. You surely helped me a lot. I will look around and will commend if i come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is wrap you `$.ajax` calls into a function that returns a promise and handle it something like this:

```
let p1 = promiseAjax1()
           .then(result => {result: result, err: null})
           .catch(err => {result: null, err: err})

let p2 = promiseAjax2()
           .then(result => {result: result, err: null})
           .catch(err => {result: null, err: err})

Promise.all([p1, p2])
    .then(results => {
         p1response = results[0];
         p2response = results[1];
         // here you can check for errors in p1response or p2response, by checking eg if p1response.err == null
    })
```